# Twin Prime Algorithm Optimization

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x, primes

I have wrote the following algorithm to print out the Nth twin prime numbers:

```
def isprime(x):
    for i in range(2, (x + 2) / 2):
        if x % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

inputIndex = int(raw_input())        
tempIndex = 1
n=2
while True:
    if isprime(n) & isprime(n + 2):
        if inputIndex == tempIndex:
            print "%d,%d" % (n,n+2)
            break
        else:
            tempIndex += 1
    n += 1
```

I am looking to optimize the speed and cannot import libraries like `math` and so or store a list of primes.

Comment: Python is surprisingly good, although of course C will be typically be faster.  At this point concentrating on the algorithms will give you far larger gains.  Look at one of rhw's Python SoEs (numpy or non-numpy) that Caridorc references, and modify to print just the twin primes.  They are simple, small, and very fast.  After doing that, if you still want more speed, look into modification to not sieve modular values that can't be twin primes.

Answer (score 6):

**A better `isprime` check**

At the moment, your function returns that 0 and 1 are prime, this is not what I have learnt.

**A faster `isprime` check**

You check primality by testing divisibility of various candidates between `2` and `(x + 2)/2` (non included). You'd better check for candidates between `2` and `sqrt(x)` (included) as the smallest divisisor will be no bigger than this.

Here's the corresponding code from my toolbox :

```
def is_prime(n):
"""Checks if a number is prime."""
if n < 2:
    return False
return all(n % i for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1))
```

**Itertools is good**

Instead of going through `n` by incrementing it, you can use `itertools.count`

```
for n in itertools.count(2):
    if isprime(n) & isprime(n + 2):
        if inputIndex == tempIndex:
            print "%d,%d" % (n,n+2)
            break
        else:
            tempIndex += 1
```

**A bit of math**

You know that twin primes will be odd (if you are not convinced of this, just think about it). Therefore, you can limit yourself to the search of odd numbers : `for n in itertools.count(3, 2):`.

**Don't check things twice**

At the moment, the primality of the same number is checked twice. A way not to do so would be to generate prime numbers and to check this to generate twin pairs.

```
def yield_odd_primes():
    for n in itertools.count(3, 2):
        if isprime(n):
            yield n

def yield_twin_pairs():
    p1, p2 = 0, 0
    for p in yield_odd_primes():
        p1, p2 = p2, p
        if p1 + 2 == p2:
            yield p1, p2

inputIndex = 1500
for i, (p1, p2) in enumerate(yield_twin_pairs()):
    if i + 1 == inputIndex:
        print "%d,%d" % (p1, p2)
        break
```

**Better user experience**

When I ran your code for the first time, nothing happened and I thought Python was just crunching numbers. After a while, I had a look at the code and realised that the script was waiting for some input.
By adding a prompt, you make this much clearer :

```
inputIndex = int(raw_input('Please enter an index: '))
```

**Code organisation**

At the moment, when one imports your code, he gets the prompt and everything. The usual way to do is to put the code "actually doing something" behind an [if-main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) guard.

**More code organisation**

Your can split your code into smaller function. I found quite useful writing the following function to take the nth element of an iterable :

```
def get_nth_element(iterable, index):
    for i, e in enumerate(iterable):
        if i == index:
            return e
```

**Tests**

For such an algorithmic oriented problem, it is easy and a good habit to write test to ensure you do not break anything as you go through modifications.

The hard part is sometimes to rewrite your code in such a way that testing is made easy. It is now the case with my final version of the code.

**Final code**

```
import math
import itertools

def isprime(n):
    if n < 2:
        return False
    return all(n % i for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1))

def yield_odd_primes():
    for n in itertools.count(3, 2):
        if isprime(n):
            yield n

def yield_twin_pairs():
    p1, p2 = 0, 0
    for p in yield_odd_primes():
        p1, p2 = p2, p
        if p1 + 2 == p2:
            yield p1, p2

def get_nth_element(iterable, index):
    assert index >= 0
    for i, e in enumerate(iterable):
        if i == index:
            return e

if __name__ == "__main__":
    inputIndex = int(raw_input('Please enter an index: ')) - 1
    print(get_nth_element(yield_twin_pairs(), inputIndex))
```

**Some math to make the code faster**

At the moment, we check the primality of each and every odd numbers. We can do better by considering division by 6 : all numbers can be written :

```
6k + 0 -> divisible by 2 & 3
6k + 1 -> potential prime
6k + 2 -> divisible by 2
6k + 3 -> divisible by 3
6k + 4 -> divisible by 2
6k + 5 -> potential prime
```

Thus, except for the obvious pair (3, 5), the only way two prime numbers can be separated by two are if they can be written (6*k + 5, 6*k + 7).

Once you have this, the code pretty much writes itself :

```
def yield_twin_pairs():
    yield (3, 5)
    for i in itertools.count(5, 6):
        if isprime(i) and isprime(i+2):
            yield (i, i+2)
```

Comment: Thanks!! but I must not use any libraries rather then built in functions

Comment: I've added more comments. Also you can easily get rid of the dependency on itertools.

Answer (score 2):

**A faster `isprime` check**

Checking even numbers before and then only looping over only odd numbers makes this twice as fast.

```
def isprime(n):
    if n < 2:
        return False
    if n % 2 == 0 and n != 2:
        return False
    for i in range(3,int(math.sqrt(n)),2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

**An even faster `isprime` check**

[All primes (past 2 and 3) are of the forms 6n+1 and 6n-1](https://primes.utm.edu/notes/faq/six.html).

```
def isprime(n):
    # The same as above

primes = []
for i in range(6,MAX,6):
    if isprime(i+1):
        primes.append(i+1)
    elif isprime(i-1):
        primes.append(i-1)
```

**An extremly fast prime checker**

If you need to make several test in a row, the [Sieve of Erastothenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is the best method

```
MAX = 1000 # depends on your needs
def eratosthenes(n):
    # Taken from Rosetta Code
    multiples = set()
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        if i not in multiples:
            print(i)
            multiples.update(range(i*i, n+1, i))

primes = eratosthenes(MAX)
def is_prime(n,primes):
    return n in primes
```

If you  are really really desperate about performance [look here for faster-than-you-can-imagine implementations of the sieve of Eratostenes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n).

Comment: Using the Eratosthene sieve is not that convenient here as it is hard to determine a (precise enough) upperbound for the n-th pair of twin numbers.

Comment: Maybe you can just create a huge sieve overnight and then just read it from a file.